# Transaction in DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I want to know a bit more about DSS transaction handling. I've been reading up on boxcarring and distributed transactions, but that's not what I'm looking for. Boxcarring is statefull (the client needs to maintain a session) and my transaction is within the same database and not distributed.

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem/challenge:
- I have a set of related table. They are related by primary/foreign key relations. I need to update/insert objects in the related tables. Can I do this in a set of nested update queries? And if so, what happens when one of the updates fails? Will all the inserted/updated objects rolled back? (I'm using the MySQL XA Driver)

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, just the nested query mechanism will not work. Since in the normal mode, the requests are committed for each nested query. So the only way I can see for doing it is using XA transactions with the usage of JMS. Basically, when using JMS with distributed transactions switched on, it will create a single global transaction and all other requests in the data services (including nested queries) will join that, and all the queries will execute transactionally. Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Anjana.